# How to extract specific value from XML either using Xpath or XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to extract value for each AvamarGrid on the basis of Day.

```
  <AvamarGridTime Day="Monday">
    <AvamarGrid>frk-opavautl921</AvamarGrid>
  </AvamarGridTime>
  <AvamarGridTime Day="Tuesday">
    <AvamarGrid>ftc-opavautl961</AvamarGrid>
    <AvamarGrid>ftc-opavbutl921</AvamarGrid>
    <AvamarGrid>ptc-opavautl981</AvamarGrid>
  </AvamarGridTime>
  <AvamarGridTime Day="Wednesday">
    <AvamarGrid>lhr-opavautl941</AvamarGrid>
  </AvamarGridTime>
a
  <AvamarGridTime Day="Thursday">
    <AvamarGrid>sf1-its-bku-t01</AvamarGrid>
    <AvamarGrid>sf1-opavautl901</AvamarGrid>
  </AvamarGridTime>
  <AvamarGridTime Day="Friday">
    <AvamarGrid>par-opavautl921</AvamarGrid>
  </AvamarGridTime>
</AvamarGrids>
```

I am using below XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Day>
      <xsl:for-each select="//AvamarGridTime">
        <xsl:if test="//AvamarGridTime[@Day=&quot;Monday&quot;]">
          <xsl:value-of select="AvamarGrid" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Day>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, getting below output, instead of just : frk-opavautl921

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Day>frk-opavautl921ftc-opavautl961lhr-opavautl941sf1-its-bku-t01par-opavautl921</Day>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test:

```
<xsl:if test="//AvamarGridTime[@Day=&quot;Monday&quot;]">
```

checks the existence of a `AvamarGridTime` element whose `Day` attribute is Monday **in the entire XML input**. This returns true for every one of the checked nodes. To test only the current node, change it to:

```
<xsl:if test="@Day=&quot;Monday&quot;">
```

Or do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/AvamarGrids">
    <Day>
        <xsl:value-of select="AvamarGridTime[@Day='Monday']/AvamarGrid" />
    </Day>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

In order to create a separate `Day` element for each `AvamarGrid` within the selected `AvamarGridTime`, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="/AvamarGrids">
    <xsl:for-each select="AvamarGridTime[@Day='Tuesday']/AvamarGrid">
        <Day>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </Day>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However, do note that the result is an XML fragment. If you want to produce a well-formed XML document, you must add a root element.

Comment: when I am using above XSLT for Tuesday, I am getting only first output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Day>ftc-opavautl961</Day> But I need all three grids name

Comment: What should the output look like in this case?

Comment: <Day>ftc-opavautl961</Day>
  <Day>ftc-opavbutl921</Day>
  <Day>ptc-opavautl981</Day>

Comment: Above should be the output for this: <AvamarGridTime Day="Tuesday">
    <AvamarGrid>ftc-opavautl961</AvamarGrid>
    <AvamarGrid>ftc-opavbutl921</AvamarGrid>
    <AvamarGrid>ptc-opavautl981</AvamarGrid>
  </AvamarGridTime>

Comment: See the addition to my post.